# What ways are there to cast life restoring magic without paying monetary or valuable material costs?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, resurrection

An example of a method which gives the party access to free resurrection magic is casting True Polymorph to become a Planetar. Planetars can cast Raise Dead 3/day without paying the material cost.

This is not a duplicate of [Are there any spell casters that can cast life giving spells without 'expensive' components?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/161360/14873) because I believe there are more methods of getting access to free resurrection than simply being these spellcasters. Also, the methods by which players gain access to those spellcasters may not exist within the system and may need the story to provide them.

What ways exist for a party of adventurers to get access to free resurrection?

Wizards of the Coast content only.

Comment: Are you looking only for ways for the entire party to have access to free resurrection--or does it count if a particular party member has access to it only for themselves?

Comment: @guildsbounty Ideally for everyone

Comment: @NautArch I'm looking for the means by which an adventuring party gets access to free resurrection. This can be by spells. For example, casting Conjure Celestial to produce a Hollyphant. Casting Conjure Celestial is the means by which the adventuring party gets access to free Raise Dead.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I think you're right and it's details we need. But I am concerned this is just a "find all this stuff for me" question.

Comment: @NautArch I think I agree with that concern...I started writing an answer and found myself just searching dndbeyond for things that can do what he asks...

Comment: @NautArch Any mechanical in-game means where the party can do X and X -> ...  -> cast Resurrection for Free. I've mentioned two so far as examples of what I mean. I suspect there are more.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're asking for this? Are you trying to cheap out as a player or are you the DM worried about your players doing so. Having the reason *why* you're looking for a list can be a great (and often improves the quality/opinion of a question).

Comment: @Someone_Evil One of the games I'm playing in is going to be in a distant plane, far from civilization for a long while. Access to quality cut diamonds and money are not a guarantee and we're already broke spending money on supplies for our journey. We have had some close calls recently so it's about time we start thinking of player deaths as a possibility and think about how to deal with them.

Comment: Based on that description, you're really asking the duplicate question, "How can the party resurrect without the expensive diamonds?"

Comment: @NautArch Vaguely. This is more of an "we'll solve it if we can" situation, rather than a desperate search for a saving grace. Eventually, the plan is to find a way back to the Material Plane or civilized places within another plane. There is quite some adventure expected in between, though.

Comment: @MivaScott The question linked above is not that question. That question is "what spellcasters can do this" not "how can a party get access". That subtle difference covers options I would like to find as well.

Comment: I think to answer this, we need to start with either the actual problem so we can provide solutions that could include this, or you need to provide the constraints that we need to make an answer applicable to your party (what level are you, what classes, what spells are known, can you buy magic items, how often do you have access to either finding or purchasing magic items, does your DM allow casters to pick their conjured creatures, etc) Although if you can purchase a magic item, you can probably purchase the diamond...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of options...

#### Wish

Let's go ahead and get this one out of the way. I'm not talking about using Wish to just Wish someone back from the dead, because that's a "strenuous use of the spell" which would (per your opinion on Reincarnate, count as a Cost), simply use Wish's ability to

> duplicate any other spell of 8th level or lower. You don't need to meet any requirements in that spell, including costly components. The spell simply takes effect.

So, Wish for the 7th level spell Resurrection, and they're alive at no cost beyond a 9th level Spell Slot. Alternatively, you may pre-empt the risk of death by Wishing for Clone spells for the whole party.

#### True Polymorph

You covered this in your question, Turn into a creature with component-free access to resurrection magic, such as a Planetar.

#### Divine Intervention

Like wish, this ability can do basically anything as long as your DM goes for it. Until you are 20th level, the odds of it actually working are fairly slim--but it offers a cost-free (apart from the cooldown) way to raise the dead.

#### Be [Zealot Barbarians](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheZealot)

If everybody in the party takes a 3 level multiclass Dip into barbarian and takes the Path of the Zealot subclass, they can acquire the following Class Feature

> **Warrior of the Gods**
> At 3rd level, your soul is marked for endless battle. If a spell, such as raise dead, has the sole effect of restoring you to life (but not undeath), the caster doesn’t need material components to cast the spell on you.

#### Acquire a [Rod of Resurrection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/rod-of-resurrection)

This grants the following option:

> The rod has 5 charges. While you hold it, you can use an action to cast one of the following spells from it: heal (expends 1 charge) or resurrection (expends 5 charges).

Spells cast through magic items do not consume material components ([see here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94123/do-spells-cast-through-magic-items-require-expensive-material-components)) This is, however, an edge case because...

> The rod regains 1 expended charge daily at dawn. If the rod is reduced to 0 charges, roll a d20. On a 1, the rod disappears in a burst of radiance.

It can only be used to Resurrect once every 5 days, and has a 1/20 chance to vanish.

#### Scroll of [Rez Spell]

Scrolls require the expenditure of their costly material components when they are created. As long as *someone else* created the resurrection spell and the party acquired it for "free" in the course of adventuring, it's a Free Resurrection. The same applies to Spell Gems.

#### [Artifact](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/sentient-magic-items-artifacts#Artifacts) with the proper Major Beneficial Property

One of the possible Major Beneficial Properties of an Artifact is...

> While attuned to the artifact, you can use an action to cast one 4th-level spell (chosen by the DM) from it. After you cast the spell, roll a d6. On a roll of 1–5, you can’t cast it again until the next dawn.

There are versions of this property for spells up through 7th level, and there are several life-restoring spells that would fit into that range.

#### Convince something to do it

If you can locate a creature capable of raising the dead without components, then social skills may be able to persuade them to do it. For example, casting Plane Shift (or Gate) to go visit somewhere with Celestials and Persuading, Deceiving, or Intimidating them into doing it.

#### Mind Effecting Magic

If you can locate a creature capable of raising the dead without components, there are all kinds of mind effecting spells that can "convince" them to help. Suggestion or Charm Monster on the lower end, Dominate Monster on the higher end. You will have to work fast with these, as Charm Monster and Dominate Monster have a Duration that's the same as the casting time of most Resurrection Magic.

Comment: @NautArch If I find anything else, I'll add em--but that's all I could find in a first pass.

Comment: @NautArch There is some overlap, however Rod of Resurrection and being a Zealot Barbarian would not be valid responses to the linked question. There are likely more answers to this question that are not answers to the linked question and I hope to find those.